# access tables for a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, recordset

How to set a position in a Table in Microsoft Access, basically I am looping through records and inserting values as I go. Since I'm using a recordset.movenext, every next value gets inserted in the next row. I'm trying to insert all values in the same row.

Comment: I have 2 recordsets. One is rs1 which hold the data I select. rs2 is my table. I am looping through rs1 and inserting values in rs2 (column1, column2, column3). Because I do rs1.moveNext, each subsequent value I insert, gets inserted in the next row (1,2,3). So I'm trying to loop through the data and insert everything in a single row, as I'm using that row for my report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access reports VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411309/access-reports-vba)

Comment: You asked this question already, you were told how to do it.  No, you probably won't get someone to answer multiple identical questions.

Comment: Difficult to know what you're asking.  You need to populate rs2(column1, 2 & 3) before you execute rs1.movenext.  Just guessing from the limited info you provided.  You'll get a clear answer if you post a clear question -- especially if you post your code so far or a sample of it.  There are experienced experts available if you post clearly.

Comment: Problem resolved. I was looping through my rs1 and each time i did .moveNext, the data I'd try to insert into my table would get inserted a row below the previous value. All I changed was I only had 1 instance of rs2.addNew, and at the end one instance of rs2.update and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. I was looping through my rs1 and each time i did .moveNext, the data I'd try to insert into my table would get inserted a row below the previous value. All I changed was I only had 1 instance of rs2.addNew, and at the end one instance of rs2.update and it worked.